# Google Compute Engine (GCE) email delivery solution?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've just setup several instances on Google Compute Engine and getting trouble with email delivery system since GCE blocks outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587.

GCE provides details solution at: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#mailserver to using postfix to send email via smtp.gmail.com using Google Account.

The problem is Gmail has its own sending limits and it will be a big problem for high traffic website which need to send email notifications heavily.

Is there anyone has a solution to send more higher sending limits for GCE instances?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
T

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the same page:

> **Blocked Traffic**
>
> Traffic on these ports to and from the Internet are blocked or
>   restricted for all Google Compute Engine instances. If you think you
>   have a compelling reason to allow this traffic, please contact the
>   Google Compute Engine team at gc-team@google.com.
>
> - All outgoing traffic to port 25 (SMTP) is blocked
> - Most outgoing traffic to port 465 or 587 (SMTP over SSL) is blocked except
>     for known Google IP addresses

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic

It looks like you'll need to have a compelling reason to allow the traffic for your application; I'm presuming that hitting GMail delivery limits might be a reason.  Note that companies like SendGrid also offer email delivery and management (bulk email as a service) with an HTTP interface that you could call from GCE.

Answer (score 7):

We've updated our documentation to include SendGrid as an additional option. You probably want to take another look.

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail?hl=en

Comment: well, somehow there is something missing ...  Did the integration with sendgrid in different forms.  But outgoing traffic still seems to be blocked.  From my instance `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net
Trying 5.153.47.203...
Trying 5.153.47.202...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: Which port are you trying to connect to?

Comment: 587.  Which is what sendgrid suggests: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

Comment: Our documentation calls out the use of port 2525 which sendgrid should listen at. Standard ports will not work.

Comment: as this ought to be in a different thread, I have question detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851366/configuration-rails3-actionmailer-for-google-compute-engine-times-out  I've basically been through both!

Comment: firewall rule set to Source Ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:2525. `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 2525
Trying 5.153.47.202...
Connected to smtp.sendgrid.net`

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to sign up for Amazon SES and get the API credentials and endpoint to send mail from google cloud without any google limitations.

You can use any similar API as well.