# Configuration rails3 actionMailer for Google Compute Engine times out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-compute-engine

Getting a:

```
Timeout::Error (execution expired):
  app/controllers/acts_controller.rb:192:in `send_message'
```

GCE requires sendgrid and following [there indications](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html) I adapted the port to "2525" as per [GCE's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail).  So the environment.rb file is

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  :password => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
  :domain => ENV["DOMAIN"],
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 2525,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

# Initialize the rails application
Myapp::Application.initialize!
```

The environment variables are defined in a yaml file with

```
SENDGRID_USERNAME:  'my_username'
SENDGRID_PASSWORD:  'pswd'
DOMAIN:  'domain.tld'
```

This being still in development mode, development.rb defines

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'smtp.sendgrid.net' }
```

What could be at the source of the timeout?

EDIT:
On the assumption of a bad connection

```
telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 2525
Trying 5.153.47.202...
Connected to smtp.sendgrid.net.
```

Comment: rule set as Source Ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:2525

Answer (score 1):

in your development.rb try to modify the **config.action_mailer.default_url_options** to:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 2525
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, behaviour remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! I was using port 587, changing to 2525 works!