# Rails not accessing mailer functions on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-compute-engine, sendgrid

A Ubuntu 14.04 instance on google compute engine is supposed to host rails3 applications served via Passenger/nginx.  The instance has sendmail installed.  The GCE instance has firewall rule

```
Source Ranges: 0.0.0.0/0   Allowed Protocols or Ports: tcp:2525
```

established and is configured to send mail via sendgrid.  `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 2525` does connect and allows to send e-mail via that connection.  So traffic should flow.

However none of the following combinations don't hit a timeout.  Nginx logs don't pick up the error, but the application's log does state the timeout being reached.

invocations:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings =
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =
```

followed by basic bloc

```
{
 :user_name => 'user',
 :password => 'aaabbbb',
 :domain => 'domain.tld',
 :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
 :port => 2525,
 :authentication => :plain,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

atempted in each of `environment.rb, application.rb, environments/development.rb`

Adding, before or after the settings bloc, either of these or both blocs:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    :host => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 2525
  }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

has no effect on overall behaviour.  That's 8 combos that have the same behaviour.  Not having access to GCE logs for handling these outgoing messages, I have no idea whether they are actually leaving the application properly.

Frankly, this impediment by GCE is somewhat of a showstopper, IMHO.

** Edit **
launching from console returns the following error stack:

```
Timeout::Error: execution expired
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:550:in `block in do_start'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
    from /home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
    from /home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
    from /home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
    from /home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.18/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:415:in `block in deliver_mail'
    from /home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
```

[...]

**Update**
Thanks to marilu for pointing out /var/log/syslog.

It is not getting referenced at all by these actions. So yes, it is a rails configuration issue.

Comment: Have you tried to send an email from the command line? If this works, then it's probably your configuration in Rails. In the file /var/log/syslog you can see if you're getting an error when sending an email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuration rails3 actionMailer for Google Compute Engine times out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851366/configuration-rails3-actionmailer-for-google-compute-engine-times-out)

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue too, working on the Google Compute Engine. Port 465 is blocked.
Google wants you to use some provider called SendGrid.

[...read Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail)

Comment: I've been through those docs and they clearly specify settings: Host: smtp.sendgrid.net
Port: 2525