# Google Compute Email Forwarding

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've noticed on the [Networking and Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic) page that Port 25 (outgoing) is blocked on Google Compute instances. 
I've configured postfix to forward emails on my instance, but I assume this won't work due to this port blocking, what are my options if I want my emails to forward (or at least work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty similar to [Google Compute Engine (GCE) email delivery solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245204/google-compute-engine-gce-email-delivery-solution)

Those answers reference https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail as a solution using SendGrid to handle the email.

That question also references a solution using smtp.gmail.com using MSA to send mail as your gmail account, which might or might not work for you depending on your needs.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, I ended up using this: www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/19043/how-to-set-up-email-forwarding-for-your-domain-using-mailgun